# Trying to understand Render Loop of AutoLayout in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

Hello I'm trying to understand Auto Layout's Render Loop which is introduced in WWDC 2018 High Performance Auto Layout

They said when Engine(Auto Layout) calculated equation of Constraints and then engine inform the value to View

At Last view call superview to call `setNeedsLayout`

So I tried to check this

this is my view

[image]

BlueView is SuperView and GreenView is Subview

and I override `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutSubviews`, `draw` and `updateConstraints` to check order of method call

the result was like this

[image]

I can understand except 4 times of `setNeedsLayout` Call and Only Superview call `setNeedsLayout`

These are my questions

1. Why only SuperView call `setNeedsLayout`
2. Why `setNeedsLayout` called 4 times in this case

This is my Code

```
class SuperView: UIView {
    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        print("SuperView : updateConstraints")
    }

    override func setNeedsLayout() {
        super.setNeedsLayout()
        print("SuperView : setNeedsLayout")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("SuperView : layoutSubviews")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        print("SuperView : draw")
    }
}

class SubView: UIView {
    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        print("SubView : updateConstraints")
    }

    override func setNeedsLayout() {
        super.setNeedsLayout()
        print("SubView : setNeedsLayout")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        print("SubView : layoutSubviews")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        print("SubView : draw")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AutoLayout Engine set value from AutoLayout Engine model (which calculated with constraints) in layoutSubviews()

setNeedsLayout called in superview because something trigger this. I think it because of changing hierarchy (adding subview) after this you add constraints to the subview (that's also trigger setNeedsLayout), change priority of constraints also trigger this.

- add or remove subviews
- intrinsicContentSize changed
- activate or deactivate constraints
- change constraints priority

This points trigger setNeedsLayout() in superview.

I hope this helped you!